# How do I take a screenshot of an element and save it as a pdf?

Tags: python, selenium

I have to take a screenshot of an element and save it as a pdf. For now I only take the screenshot and then save it but I still don't know how to turn it into a pdf.

How do I manage to do that? This is the code so far:

```
#save screenshot 
sleep(4)
constancia =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table[2]')))
constancia_screenshot = constancia.screenshot_as_png

with open('constancia.png', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(constancia_screenshot)
```

Comment: You probably want to create an HTML page with the image and then convert that using one of the many PDF conversion libraries in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Look at converting from png to pdf.

Here's one such library:
https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/

```
import img2pdf

# opening from filename
with open("name.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert('test.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from importlib import reload
import sys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")


constancia_screenshot = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot_as_png
a = io.BytesIO(constancia_screenshot)

image1 = Image.open(a)
im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
im1.save(r'a.pdf')
```

use pillow and io modules as shown , pillow converts bytes to file and then use pillow to convert it

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: I assigned the save to a variable const_pdf = im1.save(r'a.pdf') so I could print(repr(const_pdf)) to check what was saved but I get "None". Why is that?

Comment: It returns nothing , the file will be saved at the path or current directory

Comment: Will be saved as a.pdf

Comment: Oh, I see. So how do I get that pdf? Because I need to send it through email through python.

Comment: You know the location , you are setting that argument